# Installing the Subversion plugin in Intellij

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I'm new to Intellij and i'm working on svn plugin so i uninstalled the bundled subversion plugin with intellij to use my customized plugin. Now i need to get back to the bundled plugin but i couldn't find it in  "Browse JetBrains Plugins Dialog".

By the way i'm using the 12.1.7

So how to it please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundled plugins are not published to the plugin manager. If you removed a bundled plugin, you need to reinstall IntelliJ IDEA from the original distribution in order to restore it.